# In Docker Registry Allow Temporary Delete

Tags: docker

I have my docker registry working, I have my images imported. I would like to delete an image using the curl command

```
curl -X DELETE https://myhost:5000/v2/goodimage/manifest/1
```

I keep getting

```
{{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED", "message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
```

looking on Google, in my config file, I have to set

```
enabled
    deleted: true
```

I want to try to attach to the container:

```
docker attach {{containerid}}  but this hangs
```

My container is already running and I don't want to blow away my already loaded images just to delete one. Are there any solutions I am missing?

Comment: You can't attach to an *image*. You can only attach to a *container*. Furthermore, the images you have loaded in Docker have nothing to do with the images in your registry.

Comment: This has been updated to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the configuration inside of a running container. That would get lost next time the container is replaced. Instead, this should go into your environment or as a volume mount. For the environment variable, that would be:

```
REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
```

Full details on the configuration file and ways to pass in values can be found at: https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/

Note that deleting an image manifest doesn't delete the underlying blobs on disk. You need to run a separate garbage collection process for that.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

Comment: The volume mount is what saved me. Now I do not even need to worry about delete, I can delete the directory directly. Thanks for your help.